# Saved data breaks material ui text fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input, material-ui

I'm new to both react and material ui and I'm having an issue where my text fields work fine but if the user has saved data to autofill the field it breaks the styling on it. I have included the code from the component below. I apologize if this is a dumb question but I googled it and didn't find anything helpful.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Grid, Button, TextField, CardContent } from '@mui/material';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Auth from '../utils/auth';
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/client';
import { LOGIN_USER } from '../utils/mutations';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';

const LoginForm = () => {
    const [userFormData, setUserFormData] = useState({ email: '', password: '' });
    const [validated] = useState(false);
    const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);
    const [login] =useMutation(LOGIN_USER);
  
    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
      const { name, value } = event.target;
      setUserFormData({ ...userFormData, [name]: value });

    };
    const handleFormSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        const form = event.currentTarget;
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
    
        try {
          const data= await login({
            variables: {...userFormData}
          });
          console.log(data);
          Auth.login(data.data.login.token);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
          setShowAlert(true);
        }
        setUserFormData({
            username: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
          });
        };
    return (
        <Box style={{ maxWidth: 650, margin: "0 auto", padding: "20px 5px" }}>
            <CardContent sx={{fontFamily: "gotham"}}>
                <form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
                    <Grid container spacing={1}>
                        <Grid xs={12} item>
                            <TextField
                                required
                                error
                                id="outlined-error-helper-text"
                                label="Email Address"
                                fullWidth
                                color="error"
                                focused
                                style={{marginBottom:"10px"}}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                value={userFormData.email}
                                text="email"
                                name="email"
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid xs={12} item>
                            <TextField
                                required
                                error
                                type="password"
                                id="outlined-error-helper-text"
                                label="Password"
                                fullWidth
                                color="error"
                                focused
                                style={{marginBottom:"10px"}}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                value={userFormData.password}
                                text="password"
                                name="password"
                                />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid sx={{ mt: 0.25 }} xs={12} item >
                            <Button type="submit"
                            color="secondary"
                            variant="outlined" 
                            fullWidth
                            style={{ border: '2px solid', marginBottom:"15px", fontSize:"22px"}}
                            disabled={!(userFormData.email && userFormData.password)}>
                                Login
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </form>
            </CardContent>
        </Box>
    )
}

export default LoginForm;
```

broken text field

[image]

working text field

[image]

Answer (score 0):

on css file :

```
   // Change the white to any color 
    input:-webkit-autofill,
    input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
    input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
    input:-webkit-autofill:active
    {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
    }
```